# Creating new PouchDB throws "Adapter is missing" exception

Tags: javascript, requirejs, pouchdb

I'm trying to figure out what's causing this and looking through the code I haven't been able to figure it out. It also doesn't appear as though many people have run into this, from Googling it. I'm using Backbone.js with RequireJS. Does this mean I'm missing a dependency or something? Is it not able to find a file that it needs? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Don't have much code, just this:

```
var locations = new PouchDB('locations');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I figured it out. Turns out this is a bower issue. The version that's currently on bower is outdated. I guess it's different enough that using the current API documentation as a reference doesn't work. Make sure you're downloading it directly from the PouchDB site. Hope this helps someone in the future!

Comment: Yeah, pouchdb is still under development and the package manager versions tend to get stale. Always go with the nightly or build yourself from master to be sure :)